# angularjs slice method for the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, validation, slice

i have a basic page where user inputs are taken. Once accepted, the controller side performs the required functions. one input field has decimal values in it.

I need to accept decimal values from the user but at the controller side i should be able to slice it off and perform manipulations. for e.g.

$scope.params.input1 = "10.00"

I accept the values in string. so i need to chop the data after decimal point there.

The new value should be
$scope.params.input1 = "10"

How can i achieve this ? can someone please help me. i tried using the basic javascript slice but it didnt work

Comment: So you just need to change decimal to a whole number with javascript? Have you tried for example Math.round(10.00) ?

Comment: @Sergey6116- this was a string. so i needed something with string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Math.round()` if you want to round up, if the input was, say 5.60.

If you want to just get the whole number, no matter what the decimal points are, use `Math.floor()`.

Then to get it back into string format, just use, `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input ng-model="testNum"  type="number"></input>
  <button type="button" ng-click="runTestNum()"> test</button>
```

.
.
.

```
 $scope.runTestNum = function(){

            //$scope.testNum = 10.00
            console.log(Math.round ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10
            console.log(Math.floor ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10
            console.log(Math.ceil  ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10

            //$scope.testNum = 10.88
            console.log(Math.round ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 11
            console.log(Math.floor ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10
            console.log(Math.ceil  ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 11

            //$scope.testNum = 10.22
            console.log(Math.round ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10
            console.log(Math.floor ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 10
            console.log(Math.ceil  ( $scope.testNum ) ); //result : $scope.testNum = 11
      };
```